# How to install private git library to npm project?

Tags: npm, gitlab, yarnpkg, .npmrc

In a project which I work with there is private project library which is available for me directly - https://gitlab.some-project/some-utils
In package.json it is requested like

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@some-project/some-utils": "0.1.42",
    ...
   }
```

This project wasn't uploaded to npm. I created .npmrc file and put there:

```
@8some-project:registry=https://gitlab.some-project.com/some-utils
```

But when I try to "run yarn @some-project/some-utils" I get:

```
error Received malformed response from registry for "@some-project/some-utils". The registry may be down.
```

What I am doing wrongly? How to install this library to another project?

Comment: I think you might have to authenticate to the package registry. You might be able to do something like npm login (insert registry here) the. Provide your creds to sign in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just raised npm version and it works now